# Trying to make a simple option list, does not work(python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

this is my option list, it will not output the question asked and skips directly to the next cell.
For my header I have this,I have a bit more to add to this ,that's why I have many import.
the name of the image file,

````
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageColor
from PIL.ImageFilter import (
   BLUR, CONTOUR, DETAIL, EDGE_ENHANCE, EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE,
   EMBOSS, FIND_EDGES, SMOOTH, SMOOTH_MORE, SHARPEN)
import PIL.ImageOps 
f=Image.open('/Users/harrysingh/Downloads/zeus.jpg')
x=input("what would you like to with this picture of a dog? (select 1 through 8 )")
if x==1:
    f1=f.filter(BLUR)
    f1.show()
elif x==2:
    f2=f.filter(CONTOUR)
    f2.show()
elif x==3:
    f3=f.filter(DETAIL)
    f3.show()
elif x==4:
    f4=f.filter(EDGE_ENHANCE)
    f4.show()
elif x==5:
    f5=f.filter(EMBOSS)
    f5.show()
elif x==6:
    f6=f.filter(FIND_EDGES)
    f6.show()
elif x==7:
    f7=f.filter(SMOOTH)
    f7.show()
elif x==8:
    f8=f.filter(SHARPEN)
    f8.show()```
````

Comment: `input` gives a string... you need to do `x=int(x)` to make it a number before any of your `if` statements will work.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a string in your code, but you are checking for an integer. So "1" will never be equal to 1.

If you use:

```py
x=int(input("what would you like to with this picture of a dog? (select 1 through 8 )"))
```

this problem will be gone.